# Django ; How i can migrate a project done with the sqlite3 to postgresql

Tags: django, django-settings, django-manage.py

From days my friend has worked in the **OS:windows** and he did a part of the django application using the database **:sqlite3** , he give me **a backup** of his work to complete my part , on the backup i have found a database named **databaseproject.db**, My question here that am using **Linux** as an OS and **postgresql** ,
How I can migrate this database **databaseproject.db**(it's an sqlite3 database ) to postgresql.

Ps: when i have tried do the command below on the directory(after copied the project in a virtual environement on my linux):

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign \
   --exclude=auth.permission --exclude=contenttypes \
   --indent=4 > data.json
```

----> command go without errors, Here i have found the data.json contain an empty list..

So i want to know , How i can correctly migrate from sqlite3 to postgresql.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your `databaseproject.db`?

Comment: @Manzurul Hoque Rumi
I have opened  "databaseproject.db" using sublime and i have found a format of numbers like this (5351 4c69 7465 2066 6f72 6d61 7420 3300
1000 0101 0040 2020 0000 0027 0000 0022
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0038 0000 0004
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0027
002e 303a 0500 0000 010f fb00 0000 0016) , because as i say the person who give me the backup work on windows , How i can be sure that I have data there!

Answer (score 1):

Open your database by any `SQLite Viewer` and then you can make sure whether you have data or not. If you have data, then dump your them by your following command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign \
   --exclude=auth.permission --exclude=contenttypes \
   --indent=4 > data.json
```

next update your database settings with `PostgreSQL` configuration and then load your data into your `PostgreSQL` database by following command:

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be using `dumpdata` followed by `loaddata` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata).

If you see an empty dump file, you need to investigate a bit.

First, you can use something like [Sqlite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/) to make sure that data exists inside the shared database, make sure that application models contain data not the django built in models.

Then you would need to make sure that the application is added inside `INSTALLED_APPS` in `setttings.py`.

And that the application contains a file named `models.py` containing the app models.